# ActionListener problems

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have been making an applet for a project for my school but I stumbled upon a nasty error. My problem is probably quite common but I can't seem to find an answer for it. I have been getting the error:

```
The type Pyramid must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

but I have already implemented the method in there and it's spelling is correct. I checked so many times that my head hurts. My project has frozen at this process for like 3 hours now and I have no idea how to get it to work. Oh and also do you think that using 3 polygons to draw a pyramid is the best way to do it in java?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Pyramid extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    int n = 3; // vurhove
    double a, k;
    double Sok, S, V;

         public void init()  
         { 
             setLayout(null);



             TextField aT;     // textbox za osn. rub
             aT = new TextField("Osnoven rub", 20);
             aT.setBounds(20, 410, 125, 20);

             TextField lT;     // textbox za ok. rub
             lT = new TextField("Okolen rub", 20);
             lT.setBounds(20, 460, 125, 20);

             TextField SokT;   // textbox S ok.
             SokT = new TextField("Okolna povurhnina", 20);
             SokT.setBounds(20, 510, 125, 20);

             TextField ST;     // textbox S1
             ST = new TextField("Osnovna povurhnina", 20);
             ST.setBounds(20, 560, 125, 20);

             TextField VT;     // textbox za obema
             VT = new TextField("Obem", 20);
             VT.setBounds(20, 610, 125, 20);

             Button ochButton; // izchertava piramidata 
             ochButton = new Button("Izchertai");
             ochButton.setBounds(700, 435, 100, 30);
             ochButton.addActionListener(ActionOchButton);

             Button oznButton; // ozna4ava vurhovete, izpisva velichinite
             oznButton = new Button("Oznachi cherteja");
             oznButton.setBounds(700, 510, 100, 30);
             oznButton.addActionListener(ActionOznButton);

             Button iButton;   // iz4islqva veli4inite
             iButton = new Button("Izchisli");
             iButton.setBounds(700, 585, 100, 30);
             iButton.addActionListener(ActioniButton);

             add(aT);
             add(lT);
             add(SokT);
             add(ST);
             add(VT);
             add(ochButton);
             add(oznButton);
             add(iButton);

             Color bg;
             bg = new Color(168,168,168);
             setBackground(bg);


         }


         ActionListener ActionOchButton = new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

               Graphics g = getGraphics();


           int px[] = {340, 440, 490};
               int py[] = {235, 335, 235};
               g.drawPolygon(px, py, 3);

               int px1[] = {340, 415, 490};
               int py1[] = {235, 60, 235};
               g.drawPolygon(px1, py1, 3);

               int px2[] = {440, 415, 490};
               int py2[] = {335, 60, 235};
               g.drawPolygon(px2, py2, 3);

             }
         };



         ActionListener ActionOznButton = new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){



             }
         };



         ActionListener ActioniButton = new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){



             }

         };

         public void paint(Graphics g)  
         { 

             g.setColor(Color.white);
             g.drawRect(20, 20, 780, 370);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the method in your class. For example, here it is at the end of your Pyramid class:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

} //End of Pyramid class
```

Now, in this actionPerformed() method, you can determine which button was clicked and do the appropriate action. But you'll have to change a few things:

```
//make these instance variables
Button ochButton; // izchertava piramidata 
Button oznButton; // ozna4ava vurhovete, izpisva velichinite
Button iButton;   // iz4islqva veli4inite
```

Add action listener this way...

```
         ochButton.addActionListener(this);

         oznButton.addActionListener(this);

         iButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Implement actionPerformed()...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == ochButton) {
        System.out.println("ochButton clicked");
    } else if (e.getSource() == oznButton) {
        System.out.println("oznButton clicked");
    } else if (e.getSource() == iButton) {
        System.out.println("iButton clicked");
    }   
}
```

Regarding drawing a pyramid, perhaps you can draw the base triangle and the top point. Then draw lines from the top point to each point of the triangle.

Comment: Thank you Edwin your answer helped me a lot! Really informative and answers everything that I have asked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the method, plain and simple.

You need to have that method defined in your class. You're adding a bunch of other action listeners, but nowhere in your class do you implement the required method.

To clarify further, on the same level as your `init()` method, you need a `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { /* ... */ }` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have not impleented `ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `Pyramid`, only in the three anonymous instances of `ActionListener`. For `Pyramid` to implement `ActionListener`, you must implement this method in th class, not in some local variable.